# ValueError: Shapes (None, 188, 1) and (None, None, None, None) must have the same rank

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am building a CNN-LSTM network and it was working fine until I TimeDistributed the CNN layers. The program is now outputting a ValueError due to a dimension difference that I cannot seem to fix by adjusting the input dimensions. I suspect the error might be due to a difference between the CNN output size and the LSTM expected input, but I flattened the output so I really don't know.

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(1772, 300, 188, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(586, 300, 188, 1)

y_train = np.array(y_train)
y_test = np.array(y_test)
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)


model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(12, 12), activation='relu', input_shape=(1772, 300, 188, 1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (6, 6), activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by adding the TimeDistributed wrapped, you need to add a Timestep dimension.

Here you have an input with 4 dim `(batch_size, height, width, channels)` but your layer :

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(12, 12), activation='relu', input_shape=(1772, 300, 188, 1))))
```

is expecting a 5 dim input `(batch_size, timestep, height, width, channels)`.

So you need to add an other dim to your inputs !

Comment: I added a Timestep of 1 to my input, but I am still getting the same error. Do you have any other recommendations?